# Removing Blank fields from Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I use spark structured streaming to consume a kafka topic which has several type of message(different schema of each type).  I define a schema which has all fields for different kind of message.
How can i filter empty fields from dataframe for each row, or how can i read dataframe from kafka with dynamic schema.

```scala
    val inputDS = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "overview")
      .load()

    val schemaa: StructType = StructType(
      Array(
       StructField("title", StringType, true),
       StructField("url", StringType, true),
       StructField("content", StringType, true),
       StructField("collect_time", StringType, true),
       StructField("time", StringType, true),
       StructField("user_head", StringType, true),
       StructField("image", StringType, true)
      )
    )

    inputDS.withColumn("value", from_json($"value".cast(StringType), schemaa))
      //.filter()     // todo filter empty field
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

Comment: You can't remove individual columns from rows.  Maybe read it from Kafka into an RDD, figure out the message type, and move it into a dataframe of the correct schema.

Comment: @Andrew thanks a lot . I have alreday enable read it from Kafka into RDD, and i want to upgrade it from spark streaming to spark structured streaming.